# MicroService with DCOS

Tags: microservices, dcos

I decided to move to MicroService architecture, divide a project into multiple services and run those services on DCOS.It really gives a good story to project deployment and maintenance. But it makes development process complex.

For the developer, it was easy to run the application locally while implementation is in progress.Now the project is divided into multiple services and runs on DCOS which require good configuration. so to test application for the developer in the middle of implementation becomes a nightmare.

Guys, anyone is using DCOS with Microservice, can you please suggest what process you are following for internal development.

Answer (score 0):

DCOS is just a tool for your deployment, so in order to give a better answer you'd have to share more about your technology stack in your question. But here some general thoughts: There are different types/levels of testing and there are different considerations for each.

1. On unit level - This depends on what technology you use for implementing your services and is the reason why languages like go become more and more popular for server development. If you use [go](https://blog.alexellis.io/golang-writing-unit-tests/) for example, you can easily run any service you are currently developing locally (not containerized) on the dev machine. And you can easily run attached unit tests. You would either run dependent services locally or mock them up (probably depending on effort). You may also prefer asking each service team to provide mock services as part of their regular deliveries. 
   And you will require special environment settings and service configuration for the local environment.So summarized this approach will require you to have means in place to run services locally and depending on the implementation technologies you use it will be easier or harder.
2. On deployment/integration level - Setting up a minimal cluster on the [dev's local machine](https://yurisubach.com/2016/07/06/dcos-local-deployment/) and/or using dedicated testing- and staging clusters. This allows you to test the services including containerization and in a more final deployment environment with dependencies. You would probably write special test clients for this type of test. And this approach will also require you to have separate environment settings, configuration files, etc. for the different environments. Tools like [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger) become more popular for helping with debugging errors through multiple services here.
3. [Canary](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) testing. Like the name suggests - You deploy your latest service version to a small portion of your production cluster in order to test it on a limited number of users first before rolling it out to the masses. In this stage you can run user level tests and in fact your users become the testers, so it is to be used carefully. Some organizations prefer to have special beta-type-users that will only get access to those environments.